# Codeigniter create dynamic table and dropdownlist

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, dynamic, html-table

I want to create table and dynamically add rows when user click button. For the same table column I want to get data 
from database and display it in drop down list. I used ajax function to get data. Ajax function also work fine but I am unable to add
new row to table.Please help me to solve this.

Here is my code; 
I feel problem with the way I added  PHP code in JavaScript function but I don't know how to solve it. Please help me.

html
............................................

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>No</th>
                                        <th>Group</th>                                
                                        <th>Quantity</th>                                
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                        <th>Cost</th>
                                        <th><input type="button" class="addrow btn btn-success" value="Add Row "></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="body">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>1</th>
                                        <td>
                                            <?php $Treatments['#'] = 'Please Select'; ?>
                                            <?php echo form_dropdown('tcode', $Treatments, '#', 'class="form-control" id="group"'); ?>

                                        </td>

                                        <td><input type="text" class="form-control quantity" size="3" id="quantity" name="quantity[]" size="3" /></td>

                                        <td>
                                            <select class="form-control status" id="status[]" name="status[]">
                                                <option>Proposed</option>
                                                <option>Done</option>
                                                <option>Not Done</option>
                                                <option>Not Required</option>
                                            </select>
                                        </td>

 <td><input type="text" class="form-control cost" size="3" id="cost" name="cost[]" /></td>
</tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

javascript
.................................................

```
$(function(){
        $('.addrow').click(function(){
            addrow();
        });
 function addrow()
        {
            var row =($('#body tr').length-0)+1;
            var tr ='<tr>'+
                '<th>'+row+'</th>'+
                '<td>'+
                     '<?php $Treatments['#'] = 'Please Select'; ?>'+
                     '<?php echo form_dropdown('tcode', $Treatments, '#', 'class="form-control" id="group"'); ?>'+

                '</td>'+                
                '<td><input type="text" class="form-control quantity" id="quantity" name="quantity[]" size="3"></td>'+

                '<td><input type="text" class="form-control cost" size="3" id="cost" name="cost[]" /></td>'+
                '</tr>';
            $('#body').append(tr);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try using this,

```
$('#body tr:last').after(tr);
```

Fiddle link:    http://jsfiddle.net/bMyGY/1137/